# How to insert any symbol at the beggining , middle or end of BISON expression?

Tags: bison, yacc

As a beginner in Bison and Flex I want to make a program that only recognizes numbers with '!' symbol at the beginning and '_' in the middle, for example `!44_22`. I am not sure what's the best way to do it but I found out that I have to use a rule. The code below is what I made so far but it doesn't work.

```
    %{
  #define YYDEBUG 1
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        int yylex(void);
        void yyerror(char *);
        int line=0;
      
%}

%token INTEGER ERROR NEWLINE

%%

program:
    | program "!" expr "_" expr NEWLINE  { printf("NUMERICAL EXPRESSION\n");line++; }
    | program ERROR NEWLINE {line++;}
    ;

expr:
    INTEGER { $$ = $1; }
    ;

%%

yylex() {
    char c;
    c = getchar();
    
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    {
        while(c >= '0' && c <= '9' ){
            yylval = c - '0';
            c = getchar();
        }
        return INTEGER;
    }
else
if (c == '\n'){ return NEWLINE;}
else {return ERROR;}
yyerror("invalid character");
}

void yyerror(char *s) {
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}
  
int main(void) {
    yyparse();
 }
```

Comment: Such thing is normally a responsibility of the lexer. Usually, lexer discards white characters without informing the parser about them, so if you do it in bison you'll also match `!   23   _    234`.
In the lexer, you could use a regex like `![0-9]+_[0-9]+`.

Comment: @NO_NAME Thanks for the reply and the information , my problem is that when for example i insert   ( !23_234)   or   ( !   23   _    234 )   it doesnt do anything . Its like im doing something on this string     (  program "!" expr "_" expr NEWLINE )

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's wrong without seeing a complete program. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I'm missing at least the declaration of terminals (`INTEGER`, `NEWLINE`, ...) and the second part of the function `yylex`.

Comment: From what I can see right now it looks like the non-terminal `program` will never end unless there's an `ERROR`. In non-error case, `program` has to start with `program`, which has to start with `program` and so on at infinitum. One solution is to add an empty rule for `program`.

Comment: @NO_NAME i updated the code above so you can see exacly what i am doing.

Comment: This does not compile for multiple reasons. I don't think your question is about compilation problems, so before posting the code here, run it through Bison and C compiler. Fix all the problems they point out.

Comment: @NO_NAME I am so sorry about that  , i fixed it so i should run without a problem

Comment: Sorry, it's getting too late for me today. I can only give some hints on how to look for the error yourself. 1) Add `%define parse.error verbose` to your parser to have better error messages than just "syntax error". 2) Put `yydebug = 1;` before `yyparse();` to see step by step what parser does. 3) Add `%verbose` to generate an additional file that shows all the states and such. It's a good supplement for `yydebug`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes I did to your code:

1. Removed `#include <string.h>` - it was unused.
2. Added `const` to the `yyerror`'s parameter.
3. Added `%define parse.error verbose` for better error messages - makes debugging easier.
4. Added `%verbose` to make an additional file containing the generated state machine in a human-readable form. It's especially useful when you're using `YYDEBUG`.
5. Removed tokens `ERROR` and `NEWLINE`. They are not needed. (Explained below.)
6. **Replaced `"!"` and `"_"` with `'!'` and `'_'`. The former are just terminals with weird names. The latter are these specific characters. Also, replaced `NEWLINE` with `'\n'`.**
7. Replaced the empty rule for `program` with `%empty`. It does the same but it's easier to read.
8. Moved counting lines (incrementing the variable `line`) to the lexer, to make it cleaner prevent code duplication. (Btw. read about `%option yylineno`).
9. **Replaced `ERROR` with `error`. The latter is a special symbol that is automatically creates by Bison if it encounters something unexpected. Defining another one only interferes with the existing error handling.**
10. Added `yyerrok`. It informs Bison that this rule resolves the error and it can continue normal work from here. - In this case it will cause a new line character to resolve the error. (Without this Bison would treat all the wrong lines as a single error, resolving it only after finding a valid expression. Arguable, that may be better in your case. Choose what you prefer.)
11. **Added `ungetc(c, stdin);` before `return INTEGER;`. Your parser was reading a number until it found a non-digit character and then it discarded that character. This function puts it back to the input stream which allows it to be read again the next time `yylex` is called.**
12. Removed `yerror("invalid character");` because it was never called anyway and you have another error message in `yyerror`.
13. **Removed the else part of `yylex`. You can just send the character to Bison. It will generate an error automatically if there is no matching rule.**
14. Added the line number to the printed error message, just because I can.

I think that's all.

```c
%{
    #define YYDEBUG 1
    #include <stdio.h>
    int yylex(void);
    void yyerror(const char *); 
    int line = 0;  
%}

%define parse.error verbose
%verbose

%token INTEGER

%%

program:
      %empty
    | program '!' expr '_' expr '\n'  { printf("NUMERICAL EXPRESSION\n"); }
    | program error '\n' { yyerrok; }
    ;

expr:
      INTEGER { $$ = $1; }
    ;

%%

int yylex(void) {
    char c;
    c = getchar();
    
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        while (c >= '0' && c <= '9' ) { 
            yylval = c - '0';
            c = getchar();
        }   
        ungetc(c, stdin);
        return INTEGER;
    }   
    if (c == '\n')
        ++line;
    return c;
}

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "In line %i: %s\n", line, s); 
}
  
int main(void) {
    yyparse();
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked , very analytic

Comment: quick question , if i want to get float or double as input what should i change ? 
Because now i can give only integer

Comment: @martsi Your best bet would be to use a proper lexer, like Flex. You could then find float numbers by a simple regex and parse it with a standard function, like `atof`. If you want to write it by yourself like you did so far, it will be complicated and I do not find trying to do that a good use of my time.

Comment: @martsi Well, it doable if you give up on things like E notation. Then you just need to detect that the number ends on `'.'` and start a second loop there. They are catches and corner cases,... negative numbers. It's better to use a wellvtested solution.

Comment: Thank you , i will try it then to do it with flex

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that your parser is expecting the tokens `"!"` and `"_"`, but your lexer is never returning them.

These tokens are also problematic as they are strings, not integers or enums, so you can't actually return them directly in your lexer anyways.

The easiest fix for these problems is to use characters `'!'` and `'_'` instead and have your lexer return them.  You add a line to your lexer

```
else if (c == '!' || c == '_') return c;
```

before the `return ERROR;` line to return them, and change your yacc rule to

```
program '!' expr '_' expr NEWLINE
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , i tried but i am missing something .. my code needs rewrite